# Validate uniqueness of value between multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I understand that validating uniqueness of a standard, single field like "username" is easy. However, for something that has an unlimited number of inputs like, for example, "Favorite Movies" where a user can add as many favorite movies, is something I can't figure out.

They can choose to add or remove fields via the builder, but how do I ensure that no two or more entries are duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that when using nested attributes, you can only validate what's already in the database and not new duplicate occurrences. So, a validation extension (below) with memory validation is really the only option, unfortunately.

```
#user.rb

class User
  has_many :favorite_movies

  validate :validate_unique_movies

  def validate_unique_movies
    validate_uniqueness_of_in_memory(
      favorite_movies, [:name, :user_id], 'Duplicate movie.')
  end
end

#lib/extensions.rb

module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def validate_uniqueness_of_in_memory(collection, attrs, message)
      hashes = collection.inject({}) do |hash, record|
        key = attrs.map {|a| record.send(a).to_s }.join
        if key.blank? || record.marked_for_destruction?
          key = record.object_id
        end
        hash[key] = record unless hash[key]
        hash
      end
      if collection.length > hashes.length
        self.errors.add_to_base(message)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I found this one can show error messages to each nested attribute: http://techbrownbags.wordpress.com/2014/02/05/rails-validation-of-cocoon-nested-forms/

Comment: Hello @stewart715, I have also the same issues. but i want to set uniq on new duplicate occurrences of nested attributes.

Answer (score 7):

I think the easiest way to accomplish something like this is to validate the uniqueness of something in a scope. I can't say for sure how it would fit in your scenario since you did not describe you model associations but here is an example of how it could work in a FavoriteMovie model:

```
class FavoriteMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :movie_name, :scope => :user_id
end
```

This makes sure that there can't be two movie names that are the same for one specific user.

Comment: This seems like it should work but I'm using in my user.rb: 

`has_many :movies, :dependent => :destroy`

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :movies`

I have exactly what you posted (my class is Movie though) and it seems to be ignoring it altogether, any suggestions? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Okay, if you have move, :through => :something, it doesn't sound like it is exactly like my scenario. Keep in mind that if you have use a :through scenario (which I think is a good idea) then it is the through model that should have the restriction. I.e. UsersMovies validates_uniqueness_of :movie_id, :scope => :user_id. If this does not help then it would be good if you could edit your question to supply your current model structures and associations

Comment: The :scope option will work with multiple attributes as well. if you have a version number splited in three component for example:
validates_uniqueness_of :version_major, :scope => [:delivery_id, :version_minor, :version_subminor]
will ensure that you can only have one delivery with version 1.3.4.

Answer (score 2):

A very un-rails like solution to the problem would be to add a unique key constraint on the columns that in combination are required to be unique:

```
create unique index names_idx on yourtable (id, name);
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I understand how to ensure a column is unique but how do I go about adding a relationship between two columns to ensure their relationship is unique? For example, `user_id: 1` & `name: mike` and `user_id: 22` & `name: mike` should be allowed while `user_id: 1` & `name: mike` and `user_id: 1` & `name: mike` should not.

Comment: I agree with Wes, database indices is very nice to keep. They can also be created directly through Rails migrations: add_index(:table_name, [:user_id, :name], :unique => true)

Comment: This seems to work well -- although, will this need to be run every few minutes to keep the database updated? Or will this constraint not allow duplicates at all times? Very new to this end of SQL

Comment: @masedesign  Once the index is added you are done.  The database keeps the index updated as the data changes.

Comment: although now when I try to duplicate: `Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '20-GoldenEye' for key 'unique_movies': INSERT INTO `movies` (`user_id`, `name`, `created_at`, `experience`, `updated_at`) VALUES (20, 'GoldenEye', '2011-04-20 15:44:55', NULL, '2011-04-20 15:44:55')` Any suggestions?

Comment: That is the point.  The database no longer allows you to enter a duplicate combination of values in your index.  Rescue the error accordingly in the application.

Answer (score 0):

you could easly check it like:

```
params[:user][:favourite_movies].sort.uniq == params[:user][:favourite_movies].sort
```

or in model:

```
self.favourite_movies.sort.uniq == self.favourite_movies.sort


irb(main):046:0> movies = ['terminator', 'ninja turtles', 'titanic', 'terminator' ].map {|movie| movie.downcase }
=> ["terminator", "ninja turtles", "titanic", "terminator"]
irb(main):047:0> movies.sort.uniq == movies.sort
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to create virtual attribute and check it uniqueness:

   ```
   def full_name
     [first_name, last_name].joun(' ')
   end

   def full_name=(name)
     split = name.split(' ', 2)
     self.first_name = split.first
     self.last_name = split.last
   end
   ```

   1. You can check uniqueness on the database level by fix your migration:

      ```
      CREATE TABLE properties (
         namespace CHAR(50),
         name      CHAR(50),
         value     VARCHAR(100),
       );

       execute <<-SQL
        ALTER TABLE properties
        ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint UNIQUE (namespace, name)
       SQL
      ```

Answer (score 0):

Little more modern approach: `validates` [method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates)

```
validates :movie_name, :uniqueness => {:scope => : user_id}
```